# SQL Server Profile Reusable Trace File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I can create a Trace and get it up and running with SQL Server Profiler.

However, instead of going through the process of picking everything I want to trace including a particular database everytime, I just want to save the configuration, and reopen at a later time and on other computers.

I know I can save a template with the configuration in, but that is on a particular server.

Is this possible to save the configuration to a file and open on another computer?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187482.aspx ?

Comment: Doh I was looking under the Export menu in File.  Must be too late this evening.

Comment: No problem, I'll post it as a answer so the question can be closed.